# Getting error [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource org/apache/maven/resolver/ant/antlib.xml

Tags: java, maven, ant

I am getting [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource org/apache/maven/resolver/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found. error while using the following using maven 3.1.1 and ant 1.10

`

```
      <property name="maven.ant.resolver.version" value="1.6.5"/>
      <property name="maven.ant.resolver.jar.name"
          value="ant-apache-resolver-1.6.5.jar"/>
      
      <get
          src="https://artifacthub-phx.oci.oraclecorp.com/rsys-libs/ant/ant-apache-resolver/${maven.ant.resolver.version}/${maven.ant.resolver.jar.name}"
          dest="." usetimestamp="true"/>
      
      <taskdef uri="antlib:org.apache.maven.resolver.ant"
          resource="org/apache/maven/resolver/ant/antlib.xml"
          classpath="./${maven.ant.resolver.jar.name}"/>
      
      <resolve failOnMissingAttachments="true">
          <dependencies>
              <dependency coords="org.apache.maven:maven-profile:2.0.6" />
              <exclusion artifactId="junit" />
              <exclusion groupId="org.codehaus.plexus" />
          </dependencies>
          <path refid="war.lib.path" classpath="runtime" />
          
      </resolve> 
      
      
      
  </target> `
```

Any Idea to resolve this?

Comment: Can someone having maven or ant expertise please help on this ????